# Is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac {1}{q_i+1}$ irrational?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, rational-numbers

I cannot at the moment find a way for this one:

> Does there exist strictly increasing sequence of primes $q_i$ so that we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac {1}{q_i+1} \in \mathbb Q$$

I am struggling with something a slightly less general but decided to ask it in this form.

Comment: you can find some  for which the sum is 1

Comment: @orangeskid I cannot, believe me.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin The question in the title differs from the one in the post. Can you edit it?

Comment: @PVanchinathan It differs with a good reason.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, and in fact you can find such a sequence for *any* rational $q\in\mathbb{Q}^+$; this is an easy consequence of the fact that $\sum_p \frac1{p+1}\to\infty$.  Suppose we want to get a sequence $p_i$ with $\sum_i \frac1{1+p_i}=\frac23$. Then we can proceed in stages: choose $p_1$ as the smallest prime such that $\frac1{1+p_1}\lt \frac23$; then choose $p_2$ as the smallest prime such that $\frac1{1+p_1}+\frac1{1+p_2}\lt\frac23$; etc. You should be able to show (a) that there's always another prime to choose, and (b) that the limit of the sequence is $\frac23$.

Comment: Yes, I can see that we can approach $2/3$ as close as we want, but in the limit I am not sure that all the decimals will agree. I only see that we can obtain $2/3 - \epsilon < \sum < 2/3 + \epsilon$, for every $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin That is literally the definition of an infinite sum equalling a number - that the limit of the sequence of partial sums be that number.

Comment: Yes I know that, but limit procedures that I know of only allow me to go from $\sum < 2/3$ to $\lim \sum \leq 2/3$,and  not to equality., where $\sum$ is partial sum here.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin If you can prove for every $\epsilon$ that there is a partial sum $\gt 2/3-\epsilon$ - and that's where the 'infinitude' of the sum over all primes comes into play - then you've proven that the infinite sum is equal to $2/3$.

Comment: But primes are not at all important in your reasoning here, your proof can be adapted to any series that diverges to positive infinity, is this right what I am saying?

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin That's absolutely correct (though you also need the terms to go to zero) - and rationals don't play a role either. If $\{a_i\}$ is a sequence with $\lim_i a_i=0$ and $\sum_i a_i\to\infty$, then for any $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$, there's an increasing subsequence $s_i$ with $\sum_i a_{s_i}=r$.

Comment: It tells me to avoid extended discussions in comments. I understand you, but I do not agree.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin What part do you disagree with?

Comment: Thank you for asking, I disagree that we can always find a sequence of primes that will sum to any rational or irrational number because sequence $1/p$ has strictly determined non-trivial digit-pattern and the infinite sum of some terms of that sequence will not, in my amateur opinion, be able to be summed to any number we want.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin I'm afraid that digit patterns (and in fact number theory) are completely a red herring - this is a problem in basic analysis. Given that you're summing an infinite number of values, each of which is likely to have e.g. an entirely separate period in its decimal expansion and with an arbitrary number of carries in the sum as 'interference', you can't make any meaningful assertion about what the result will or won't look like based on digit patterns.